# How to show file from specific path?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to show file from specific path, I'll implement it in RecyclerView. But I don't know how to show that file.

This is my MainActivity.java

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn_add = findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    tv_filePath = findViewById(R.id.tv_filePath);

    btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
        }
    });
}

    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 10:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String path = data.getData().getPath();
                tv_filePath.setText(path);
                uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
                toDisplay = new File(uri.getPath());
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

I've already have the file path, how to show that file from the file path?

Comment: You're going to need to add more information for this to be answerable. What type of file is it? What do you mean by "show the file"? Show it's contents? Show the path?

Comment: "I've already have the file path" -- no, you do not. A `Uri` is not a file. `getPath()` on a `Uri` only has meaning if the scheme of the `Uri` is `file`. Most likely, your scheme is not. Beyond that, what do you mean by "show that file"? Do you mean open up some other app to view the file? Do you mean read the file contents into your app? Do you mean something else?

Comment: The file is depends on what the user clicks. It could be docx, pptx, xlsx, and image file. It's like file manager, I wanna display the file that has been selected in a RecyclerView and when we click the file, we can read it.

Comment: What do you mean by "display the file" and by "we can read it"? Are you looking to have some other existing app, such as Microsoft Office, display the content? Or are you looking to display its contents within your own app, perhaps using some commercial third-party library?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for some other existing apps to display the content.

Answer (score 0):

With the Volley library, you can send your data such as string, image and video to the server.

```
 public void stringpost(){

        String url = "you web service url ";

        final String test = "test";




        StringRequest istek = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e("Cevap",response);



                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    String succes = jsonObject.getString("success");







                } catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }




            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();

                params.put("test",test);


                return params;
            }
        };
        Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(istek);



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the file exist in folder in a list of string to the adapter.

```
File folder = new File(your path);
String[] files = folder.list(); 

//folder.list(); gives you the name of all files inside that path
//folder.listFiles(); gives you the file of all files inside that path

list <String> filesNames = Arrays.asList(files);
//then u can pass files name to adapter and set your recyclerView
```